# Lista y Scripts

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando crear una lista que me permita mantener el checkbox y el scroll aunque se actualice la página y que cuando haga clic en un botón me cambie el color. He conseguido que se mantenga el checkbox y que me cambie el color de la caja.

Mis dudas son las siguientes para el código que he escrito: ¿cómo podría hacer?

1. Que se mantenga el scroll aunque se actualice la página
2. He conseguido mantener el checkbox y el botón. ¿Cómo hacerlo para el resto de ítems?

```
<style>
    .caja{border:black solid 2px; 
        width:100px; 
       margin: 20px;
        text-align: center;}
    .caja.verde{border:black solid 2px;
        background: green; 
        width:100px; 
        margin: 20px;
        text-align: center;}

</style>

    <body>
    <div class='caja' id='caja'>PEPINO</div>
    <input type='checkbox'  id='0'>
    <input type='number' name='cantidad' style='width: 3em'>
    <button id='btncomprado'>comprado</button><br>

    <div class='caja' id='caja1'>manzana</div>
    <input type='checkbox'  id='1'>
    <input type='number' name='cantidad' style='width: 3em'>
    <button id='btncomprado1'>comprado</button><br>

    <div class='caja' id='caja2'>pomelo</div>
    <input type='checkbox'  id='2'>
    <input type='number' name='cantidad' style='width: 3em'>
    <button id='btncomprado2'>comprado</button><br>
        <script>
                var btn= document.getElementById('btncomprado'),
                caja=document.getElementById('caja'),
                contador=0;
                function cambio()
                {   if(contador==0)
                {
                caja.classList.add('verde');
                contador=1
                    }
                else{caja.classList.remove('verde');
                contador=0;}   
                }
                    btn.addEventListener('click',cambio,true)
        </script> 
        <script>
                checkbox = document.getElementById('0')
                checkbox.checked = eval(window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id))
                checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
                window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, checkbox.checked)
                    })
                </script> 
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mantener el scroll aunque se actualice la página, puedes usar el método `scrollTo()` en el evento `onload` del objeto `window` para que la página se desplace a la posición donde se encontraba antes de la actualización. Por ejemplo:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var scrollPos = localStorage.getItem('scrollPos');
        if (scrollPos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
        }
    };
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('scrollPos', window.scrollY);
    };
</script>
```

Para mantener el estado de los checkboxes y botones para el resto de los elementos, puedes crear una función que reciba como parámetro el id del elemento y usarla en los eventos correspondientes, guardando la informacion tal y como lo hacias para el checkbox en el localStorage

Quedaria algo así: (si hay algun error, sorry y avisa)

```
<script>
    function setEstado(elemento) {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(elemento.id),
            btn = document.getElementById('btncomprado' + elemento.id),
            caja = document.getElementById('caja' + elemento.id),
            estado = eval(window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id));
        checkbox.checked = estado;
        if (estado) {
            caja.classList.add('verde');
        }
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (caja.classList.contains('verde')) {
                caja.classList.remove('verde');
                estado = false;
            } else {
                caja.classList.add('verde');
                estado = true;
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, estado);
        }, true);
    }
    setEstado({id: 0});
    setEstado({id: 1});
    setEstado({id: 2});
</script>
```

Comment: Buenos días me da error en  btn.addEventListener('click', function() me dice en el navegador que cannot read propierties of null,

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me explique mal, no es un scroll es el input number, el que queria que se mantuviese perdona